# Running GNU Screen with 256 colors on OS X Lion

Tags: emacs, macos

Terminal.app in Mac OS X Lion has a feature that took a long time to get implemented: 256 color support. The colors work fine. The issue I'm having is that when I run GNU Screen I do not have access to 256 colors. In screen, $TERM is set to "screen".

I've read different things in different places and am very confused. Some of these include:

- GNU Screen must be compiled with color support (How can I tell if OS X's screen was compiled this way?)
- A special terminfo file for screen-256color must be installed. Does OS X have this?
- In .screenrc, term should be set to "screen-256color".
- Certain functions in Emacs must be called for Emacs to be colorful (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuScreen#toc6)

I tried variations of these procedures and have been unsuccessful and uncertain of why I have failed. What is the most direct way for me to enable 256 colors in GNU Screen?

Comment: @PaulR You're right, but it's a good question nevertheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `screen` is not aware that it is running in a 256-color-capable `xterm`. To make programs in `screen` recognize this feature, you need to set a couple of things in your `~/.screenrc`:

```
term "screen-256color"
# terminfo and termcap for nice 256 color terminal
# allow bold colors - necessary for some reason
attrcolor b ".I" 
# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground 
termcapinfo xterm 'Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm' 
# erase background with current bg color 
defbce "on"
```

If this doesn’t work for you, your version of `screen` probably wasn’t compiled with `./configure --enable-colors256`. You can check this in the welcome screen when starting `screen`. **The default version that comes with OS X doesn’t support 256 colors.** You could check out the source and compile your own version, putting the resulting binary in your `$PATH` (I put it in `~/bin` which I added to my `$PATH`):

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/screen.git
cd screen/src
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-colors256
make   # I got a lot of warnings here, but they don't seem to matter
sudo make install
cp screen ~/bin/screen
```

Sources: [1](http://frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/) and [2](http://ryanwilliams.org/2010/Oct/09/gnu-screen-256-colours-mac-os-x)

Comment: Thank you very much. This issue has been irritating me for so long. Someone at Apple thought it was a good idea to ship a terminal emulator with 256 colours and a terminal multiplexer with 8 haha!

Comment: FWIW, I reported this as a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/), so hopefully this will get fixed in Mountain Lion.

Comment: Homebrew users: [homebrew-dupes](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes) has [a recipe for screen](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/screen.rb) including `--enable-colors256`.

    $ brew tap homebrew/dupes  # if you haven't already
    $ brew install screen

Comment: I cannot use the solution for big sur anyone could help? I have install via `brew install screen` but it still use 8 bit colors screen

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `~/.screenrc`

```
term "screen-256color"
```

And then try, it should work.

Comment: FWIW this is all I needed in 10.7.5 and 10.8.2.

Comment: @tvon I can't get it work on my OSX 10.7.5. Any idea why?